# Cropping and Uploading Image using Jcrop

Tags: angularjs, node.js, image-uploading, jcrop

I am working on **MEAN**. I have to crop an image with a selected shape and then upload it on a server, just like Facebook profile picture functionality works. So I used **JCROP** for cropping images, where I am able to select an area of the image but don't know how to save the selected area, this means I am not able to crop the image? Please suggest me a way so that I can upload the selected image after using JCROP.